# How can I record a single character using a regular expression? Or: Can I detect a string based on parts of a regex that won't be used?

Tags: regex

The second half of that title was a trainwreck, I'm sorry.

I know that there's some regex feature to do what I'm thinking of, but I can't work out or remember what it is.

I want to detect all instances of `pizza` that are *not* preceded by a `{` character, so that I can replace them with `kale`.

My solution so far is to search for `/[^{]pizza/`. There's a problem, though. That will replace `tpizza` with `kale`, removing whatever the preceding character was. I don't want that, mainly because it kills preceding spaces.

So my hypothetical solutions are:

1. Find a way to search for "pizza preceded by any non-`{` character" without having "a non-`{` character" be part of what gets 'snagged' by the regex itself, or
2. Find a way to record whatever that preceding character was, so that I can use it in my substitution string.

Unfortunately I have no idea how I'd go about doing either. Can anyone offer a tip?

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion. Lookarounds are zero width assertions, it won't consume any character.

```
(?<!{)pizza
```

This would match the word `pizza` only if it's not preceded by a `{`. Just replace the matched string `pizza` with the string you want.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qT0kF5/1)

**OR**

Capture the preceding character(any char not of `{`)  through capturing group and replace the matched chars with the chars inside group index 1 plus the string you want to add ie, `kale`

```
([^{]|^)pizza
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qT0kF5/2)